# With Bootstrap4 forms do I need labels if using input-groups

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Reading the Bootstrap4 document it has concept of input-groups, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/ and these seem to be rather like labels but more closely linked to the input.

I'm just converting non Bootstrap 4 web application to a Bootstrap 4 and it has a number of pages containing input fields. So if I use input-groups should I drop labels or do I need both ?

Here is screenshot of one of my pages, this is pre Boostrap apart from buttons, currently my labels have a background colour of light blue (that was done as an experiment previously background was white)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not treat an `input-group` as replacing a `<label>`. Labels have special meaning to the browser, especially for visually impaired folks using a screen reader.

That said, you *can* make the input-group prepend/append item a label and get the best of both worlds. Just change the `<span>` to a `<label>` and it appears to work just fine:

```
<label class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</label>
```

Comment: ok works for me to, so for so assuming I do that (for visually impaired) I just need to use these instead of my current regular labels, right ?

Comment: That's really a UI/UX decision on your part. You could use either one. Whichever you prefer the look/feel of. I'd just make sure there's a `<label>` somewhere in it.

Comment: True, but this is not my area of expertise so Im just trying to go with the crowd (one reason im using bootstrap)